# hashing password on update with mongoose

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

For hashing a password before the object is saved to mongodb, i use the built-in pre-save hook comming with mongoose. 
But what is the correct way to handle hashing during updates?

I tried to solve this with the pre-update hook, but this has some significant disadvantages, as it bypasses the model validation (e.g password length).

That was my approach (shortened):

```
userSchema.pre('findOneAndUpdate', function (next) {
    let query = this;
    let update = query.getUpdate();

    if (!update.password) {
        return next();
    }

    hashPassword(update.password, function (err, hash) {
        //handle error or go on...
        //e.g update.password = hash;
    });
});
```

So, what is the preferred way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would use a pre `'save'` middleware:

```
AccountSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
  this._doc.password = encrypt(this._doc.password);
  next();
});
```

But doing this requires to use `save` also for updating a document:

```
Account.findById(id, function(err, doc) {
    if (err) return false;
    doc.password = "baloony2";
    doc.save();
  });
```

As stated in the [documentation for update](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.update):

> [...]
>
> Although values are casted to their appropriate types when using
>   update, the following are not applied:
>
> - defaults
> - setters
> - validators
> - middleware
>
> If you need those features, use
>   the traditional approach of first retrieving the document.

A verifiable example:

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
const algorithm = 'aes-256-ctr';
const password = 'aSjlkvS89';

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:33023/test_1");
mongoose.Promise = require('bluebird');

function encrypt(text) {
  var cipher = crypto.createCipher(algorithm, password);
  var crypted = cipher.update(text, 'utf8', 'hex');
  crypted += cipher.final('hex');
  return crypted;
}

// SCHEMA -------------------------------------------------

var AccountSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    unique: true
  },
  password: String
});

var id;

AccountSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
  id = this._doc._id;
  var pwd = this._doc.password;
  console.log("hashing password: " + pwd);
  this._doc.password = encrypt(pwd);
  next();
});

// MODEL --------------------------------------------------

var Account = mongoose.model('Account', AccountSchema);

// DATA ---------------------------------------------------

new Account({
  name: "john",
  password: "baloony1"
})
.save()
.then(function(res) {
  Account.findById(id, function(err, doc) {
    if (err) return false;
    doc.password = "baloony2";
    doc.save();
  });
});
```

Extra info on the example:

- http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html
- http://lollyrock.com/articles/nodejs-encryption/

Comment: hi need your assistance on this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62066921/hashed-password-update-with-mongoose-express#

Answer (score 0):

The safer way

```
AccountSchema.pre('save', async function () {
  if (this.password && this.isModified('password')) {
    this.password = encrypt(this.password)
  }
})
```