# Hashed password update with mongoose express

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I have reviewed many discussions on this matter but none seems helpful to me.

I am using mongoose 5.5 to save user data as shown below:

My schema looks like this:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");

const userSchema = Schema({

  userName: {
    type: String
  },
  firstName: {
    type: String
  },
  surName: {
    type: String
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
});

userSchema.pre('save', async function(next){

try {
  if(!this.isModified('password')){
      return next();
  }
  const hashed = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, 10);
  this.password = hashed;

} catch (err) {
    return next(err);
  }
});

module.exports = user;
```

My registration code looks like this:

```
exports.register = async (req, res, next) => {

try {
    const user = await db.user.create(req.body);
    const {id, username} = user;
    res.status(201).json({user});
    
} catch (err) {
    if(err.code === 11000){
        err.message ='Sorry, details already taken';
    }
    next(err);
  }
};
```

Login code looks like this:

```
exports.login = async (req, res, next) => {

try {
    const user = await db.user.findOne({username: req.body.username});
    const valid = await user.comparePasswords(req.body.password);

    if(valid){

        const token = jwt.sign({id, username}, process.env.SECRET);
        res.json({id, username, token});
    }
    else{
        throw new Error();
    }        
    
} catch (err) {
    err.message = 'Invalid username/password';
    next(err);
  } 
};
```

Registration and login works well, my challenge is updating a password. I would like to compare current password with what user provides (like in login), if it is valid then update new password.

something like this:

```
exports.changepass = async (req, res, next) => {
    const user = await db.user.findOne({username: req.body.username});
    const valid = await user.comparePasswords(req.body.password);

    if(valid){

           " ?? update password and hash ?? "
    }
    else{
        throw new Error();
    }       

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using `findOneAndUpdate()` to update, try using the `pre("findOneAndUpdate")` middleware to modify the password similar to your `pre("save")`. The `pre("findOneAndUpdate")` middleware will be called every time you use `Model.findOndAndUpate()` to update your models.

You can do the same with `updateOne()` with `pre("updateOne")`

Sample:

```
// userSchema--------------------
...
userSchema.pre('save', async function (next) {
    try {
        if (!this.isModified('password')) {
            return next();
        }
        const hashed = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, 10);
        this.password = hashed;
    } catch (err) {
        return next(err);
    }
});

userSchema.pre('findOneAndUpdate', async function (next) {
    try {
        if (this._update.password) {
            const hashed = await bcrypt.hash(this._update.password, 10)
            this._update.password = hashed;
        }
        next();
    } catch (err) {
        return next(err);
    }
});

// changepass--------------------
...
if(valid){

    //" ?? update password and hash ?? "
    const result = await db.user.findOneAndUpdate(
        { username: req.body.username },
        { password: req.body.newPassword },
        { useFindAndModify: false }
    ); 
}
```

Comment: then how do I use use this schema ? like in the example above .. it is valid? update

Comment: @Denn i have edited the code for you to use. I hope this clarifies it

Comment: @Denn you can simply add this piece of code right under yours. You do not have to modify anything else. userSchema.pre('findOneAndUpdate') will be called every time you use db.user.findOneAndUpdate()

Answer (score 1):

I solved it using both middleware `Schema.pre('save')` for saving and `Schema.pre('findOneAndUpdate')` for updating the data.

In UserSchema,

```
// Hashing data before saving into database
UsersSchema.pre("save", async function (next) {
  try {
    // When password is hashed already, no need to be hashed
    if (!this.isModified("password")) {
      return next();
    }

    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, 10);
    this.password = hashedPassword;
  } catch (err) {
    return next(err);
  }
});

// Hashing data before updating into database
UsersSchema.pre("findOneAndUpdate", async function (next) {
  try {
    if (this._update.password) {
      const hashed = await bcrypt.hash(this._update.password, 10);
      this._update.password = hashed;
    }
    next();
  } catch (err) {
    return next(err);
  }
});
```

In userController,

```
    try {
    const user = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
      {
        _id
      },
      userInputValue,
      {
        // For adding new user to be updated
        new: true,
        // upsert: true,
        // Active validating rules from Schema model when updating
        runValidators: true,
        context: 'query'
      }
    );

    if (!user) return res.status(404).send("User Not Found");

    const userData = {
      user: {
        _id: user._id,
        name: user.name,
        email: user.email,
        role: user.role,
        createdAt: user.createdAt
      },
      success: {
        title: 'User Info Update',
        message: `You have updated the user ${user.name}'s info successfully.`
      }
    };

    return res.status(200).send(userData);

    // res.send(user);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).send(err);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
userSchema.pre('findOneAndUpdate', async function (next) {
  const user = this;
  if (user._update.$set.password) {
    user._update.$set.password = await bcrypt.hash(user._update.$set.password, 8);
  }
  next();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
schemaName.pre("updateOne", async function(next) {
   try {
      if(this._update.password) {
          this._update.password = await bycrpt.hash(this._update.password, 10);
      }
      next();
  } catch (err) {
      return next(err);
  }
})
```

#### Explanation:

When you're using `findOneAndUpdate()` or `updateOne()` to update, you need to use the `pre("findOneAndUpdate")` or `pre("updateOne")` middleware respectively to modify the password.
`pre("findOneAndUpdate")` or `pre("updateOne")` middleware will be called every time you use `Model.findOndAndUpate()` or `Model.updateOne()` to update your model.

Comment: You need to explain but not write only solution

Comment: @FiodorovAndrei thanks for the suggestion, I'm new here actually.

When you're using findOneAndUpdate() or updateOne() to update, you need to use the pre("findOneAndUpdate") or pre("updateOne") middleware respectively to modify the password. pre("findOneAndUpdate") or pre("updateOne") middleware will be called everytime you use Model.findOndAndUpate() or Model.updateOne() to update your model.